# Greek support in php form

Tags: php, html, forms, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using this php contact form but it does not support greek!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>My Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
 ONOMA:
 <input type="text" name="name" size="19"><br>
 <br>
 EMail:
 <input type="text" name="email" size="19"><br>
 <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="blue"> MPLE<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="green"> PRASSINO<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="orange"> PORTOKALI <br>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" value="yes" name="radio"> NAI<br>
 <input type="radio" value="no" name="radio"> OXI
 <br>
 <br>
 <select size="1" name="drop_down">
 <option>php</option>
 <option>xml</option>
 <option>asp</option>
 <option>jsp</option>
 </select><br>
 <br>
 MHNYMA:<br>
 <textarea rows="9" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

mailer.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $to = "email@email.gr";
 $subject = "Form Contact Form";
 $name_field = $_POST['name'];
 $email_field = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $option = $_POST['radio'];
 $dropdown = $_POST['drop_down'];
 foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
 $check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
 }
 $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n $check_msg Option: $option\n Drop-Down: $dropdown\n Message:\n $message\n";
 echo "Your Mail Was Sent To $to!";
 mail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
 echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `charset=UTF-8` in your meta tag.  Also make sure that you save the file with UTF-8 (rather than ANSI) encoding in whatever text editor you use.  The option should appear when you select "Save As" from the file menu

Comment: The one you've used in your example, but doing this with the file receiving won't do any harm either.

Comment: windows-1252 is purely Western European, it can't even cope with Polish, Czech etc.

Comment: I added this encoding tag before but displayed chinese...now it seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation. http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html